# Multiple Inner Join Concern

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm trying to get data at monthly level.

```
SELECT 
    c.Calendar_Month_Name, COUNT(*)
FROM
   db1 AS c
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        a.tel_num, b.postpaid_tel_num
    FROM
        db2 AS a
    INNER JOIN db3 AS b ON a.tel_num = b.tel_num
    WHERE
        a.hs_manufacturer = 'Samsung'
            AND b.postpaid_tel_num = 1) d ON c.Dim_Calendar_Dt = d.REPORT_DT
WHERE
    c.Calendar_Year_Num = 2018
GROUP BY c.Calendar_Month_Name;
```

---

REPORT_DT is present in db2 but still I get an error that says REPORT_DT does not exist

If I change the position of paratheses as follows I get an error that says, something is expected between 'REPORT_DT' and the 'where' keyword.

```
SELECT 
    c.Calendar_Month_Name, COUNT(*)
FROM
    (db1 AS c
    INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
        a.tel_num, b.postpaid_tel_num
    FROM
        db2 AS a
    INNER JOIN db3 AS b ON a.tel_num = b.tel_num
    WHERE
        a.hs_manufacturer = 'Samsung'
            AND b.postpaid_tel_num = 1) d ON c.Dim_Calendar_Dt = d.REPORT_DT
WHERE
    c.Calendar_Year_Num = 2018)
GROUP BY c.Calendar_Month_Name;
```

Comment: Is this mysql or teradata sql ?

Comment: When you join to a derived table you can only use columns that you select in that derived table.  `REPORT_DT` exists in `db2`, but not in the derived table you named `d` because you aren't selecting it.

Comment: Format your SQL properly, and it will easier to understand it - both for us and for you!

Answer (score 1):

In the first version, it looks like you need to add *REPORT_DT* to the **select** clause of your subquery **d**

Comment: Exactly. `select distinct a.tel_num, b.postpaid_tel_num` should say `select distinct a.tel_num, b.postpaid_tel_num, a.REPORT_DT`

Comment: you are correct. I forgot to add d.report_dt in the inner join. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I think a formatted query should look something like this:

```
SELECT c.Calendar_Month_Name
     , COUNT(*) 
  FROM db1 c
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT DISTINCT a.tel_num
            , b.postpaid_tel_num 
         FROM db2 a
         JOIN db3 b 
           ON a.tel_num = b.tel_num
        WHERE a.hs_manufacturer = 'Samsung'         
          AND b.postpaid_tel_num=1
     ) d
    ON c.Dim_Calendar_Dt = d.REPORT_DT
 WHERE c.Calendar_Year_Num = 2018
 GROUP 
    BY c.Calendar_Month_Name
```